# Routing to another html.erb file (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, erb

I am learning how to login from Rails and I wanted to know one thing:

I have several files which I want to show when a certain condition is met, in this case logging in will redirect me to another file called starter.html.erb

I am trying to redirect it through both the controller and the routes files and I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/app/views/usuarios/starter.html.erb"
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Controller portion:

```
redirect_to search_starter_path
```

routes.rb portion:

```
get "/search/starter" => redirect("/app/views/usuarios/starter.html.erb")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the controller#action syntax to redirect. Example: if your controller is usuarios_controller.rb you should have inside an action named starter. Then in your routes.rb put this entry:

```
get "search/starter" =>  'usuarios#starter'
```

Comment: And how can I redirect it to the page I want it to go? starter.html.erb?

Comment: "rake routes" in the console will give you the available prefixes (first column from the left) and the requests issued by those prefixes (yes, you should add _path to the end of them and use them with redirect_to).

Comment: After accomplished what you want to do, I suggest to use or at least do some research on the gem "devise" which can manage the authentication workload.